# Convertion between compound CRS with pyproj

Tags: python-3.x, coordinates, pyproj

I'm trying to convert the (x,y,z) coordinate from a compound CRS to another one. I came across [this example online](https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj/issues/630), and it does work for me.

```
import pyproj

cmpd_crs = pyproj.crs.CompoundCRS(name="WGS 84 + EGM96 height", components=["EPSG:4326", "EPSG:5773"])
trans = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs(cmpd_crs, "EPSG:4979") # epsg 4979 is Geographic 3D CRS 
trans.transform(45, -122, 10)
```

This reports

```
(45.0, -122.0, -10.386833190917969)
```

However, when I tried to do other transformations between compound CRS using EPSG codes, it doesn't work. For example:

```
import pyproj

c1 = pyproj.crs.CompoundCRS(name="NAD83+cgvd28",components=["EPSG:4617","EPSG:5713"])
c2 = pyproj.crs.CompoundCRS(name="NAD83+cgvd2013",components=["EPSG:4617","EPSG:6647"])

transformer = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs(c1,c2)
transformer.transform(45, -122, 10)
```

This reports (without any change)

```
(45.0, -122.0, 10.0)
```

And

```
import pyproj

c1 = pyproj.crs.CompoundCRS(name="WGS84 + EGM96", components=["EPSG:4326", "EPSG:5773"])
c2 = pyproj.crs.CompoundCRS(name="NAD83+cgvd2013",components=["EPSG:4617","EPSG:6647"])

transformer = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs(c1,c2)
transformer.transform(45, -122, 10)
```

This reports (without any change)

```
(45.0, -122.0, 10.0)
```

Also

```
import pyproj

c1 = pyproj.crs.CompoundCRS(name="NAD83+cgvd28",components=["EPSG:4617","EPSG:5713"])

transformer = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs(c1,"EPSG:6649")
transformer.transform(45, -122, 10)
```

This reports (still without any change)

```
(45.0, -122.0, 10.0)
```

Any insights? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Do you have the transformer grids installed?

Comment: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/latest/transformation_grids.html

Comment: @snowman2 Thank you for the information. However, after I install the transformer grids,  I still don't get the transformed coordinate, especially the height. It reminds me that I got a 'HT2_2010v70_CGG2013a.byn' file from the NRCan website [link](https://webapp.geod.nrcan.gc.ca/geod/data-donnees/geoid.php?locale=en),  do you have any insights on how would I use this .byn file to transform between vertical datums (CGVD28 and CGVD2013) with pyproj? Thanks a lot.

Comment: How did you install the grids?

Comment: @snowman2 I followed the instruction on [link](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/latest/transformation_grids.html)  by using conda install -c conda-forge proj-datumgrid-europe proj-datumgrid-north-america proj-datumgrid-oceania proj-datumgrid-world

Comment: That should work if the grid is there. You may want to look into the PROJ mailing list and see if they have advice.